# Moving array pointer isn't changing ADDRESS of start

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *test = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*9);
    test = "testArry";
    cout << &test << " | " << test << endl;
    test++;
    cout << &test << " | " << test << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Result:

```
004FF804 | testArry
004FF804 | estArry
```

I don't understand how it's possible that I had moved my array pointer and address didn't change.

Comment: `&test` is the address of `test` itself, not what it is pointing to.

Comment: Ok, as I thought, but how can I get ADDRESS what i'm looking for?

Comment: Note that malloc is never used in C++.

Comment: @Yas - You might want to check the answer.  :-)  Also, `test = "testArry";` doesn't move the text to the memory you `malloc`'ed, it just changes the pointer (and leaks the allocated memory). You can *never* figure out how C style strings work by testing, you will *have to* read up on that (`strcpy` for example). Otherwise use a C++ `std::string` and save yourself from a lot of trouble.

Comment: When I asked about it there wasn't any answer.
I was resolving an exercise and I only used IO from c++ for tests.
In exercise rules they marked that we are had not to use string.h and other datatypes than char (and char*).

Answer (score 9):

The pointer did change. You're just not printing it. To print the pointer `test`:

```
cout << (void*) test << endl;
```

`&test` is the memory location where `test` is stored.
`test` is the value that you incremented with `test++` (i.e., you didn't increment `&test`).

When you do `cout << test` the overload of `operator<<` that gets picked is one that takes a `const char*` and treats it as a C-style string, printing the characters it points to. The cast to `void*` avoids this behavior in order to print the actual value of `test`, instead of the value it points to.

Comment: <pedantic>It's probably a good idea to say why the cast to `(void*)`</pedantic>

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
cout << &test << " | " << test << endl;
```

expression `&test` yields the address of the variable `test` itself that is evidently is not changed. It is the value stored in the variable was changed.

If you want to output the value of the variable `test` that is the value that points inside the string literal you should write

```
cout << ( void * )test << " | " << test << endl;
```

Take into account that there is a memory leak in the program because after allocating memory the pointer is reassigned. And sting literals have types of constant character arrays. So the pointer test should be declared like

```
const char *test;
```